# Setting a default value for @Html.TextAreaFor()

Tags: html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am using asp.net core razor engine.  I am trying to set a default value for a text area.  I have looked at other posts and I seem to following the advice.  However the default value I set does not  show up.

Here is my code in my .cshtml page

```
@Html.TextAreaFor(d=>d.Users_id, new {@Value =TempData["id"]})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's the wrong way to set a default value. The value of bound inputs is determined by `ModelState`, which itself is composed of the values from `Request`, `ViewData`/`ViewBag` and finally `Model`. Despite setting the `value` attribute to something explicitly, Razor will back fill the value with whatever it finds in `ModelState` for that property.

If you want a default value, then you can either set it on the property itself:

**C# 6**

```
public int Users_Id { get; set; } = 1;
```

**C# Previous**

```
private int? users_Id;
public int Users_Id
{
    get { return users_Id ?? 1; }
    set { users_Id = value; }
}
```

Or, set the value manually on your model in your action:

```
model.Users_Id = TempData["id"];
```

Obviously, since you're using `TempData` here, you'll have to go with the second option, but the first method is better if you're dealing with a constant default.

Just bear in mind that, `Model` is the last source for `ModelState`, so if you do something like have an action param named `users_id` (case insensitive) or set `ViewBag.Users_Id` (again, case insensitive), that will take priority over everything else.